# Beginner in R programming

Tags: probability, self-study

I face a problem when dealing with the question on the image and the value given was $n=7$, $m=11$, $t=18.72$. The detail of the question is on the picture attached.
Thanks a lot
 [image]

Comment: Hi Yue, welcome to CrossValidated.SE.  This looks like a homework problem, so I have tagged it as self-study.  For these types of questions, we do not like to give direct answers, but would instead like to hear what you have already tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: Please see the [help/on-topic]. To the extent that this is about coding rather than primarily a question about a statistical issue, it is off topic. Further, as coursework/homework.assignment work, you need to show what you have tried to do, and ask specific questions about the problem you have. Either of these is sufficient for closure.

Comment: I had assign the variable and I let x=rpois, but I don't know I need to run this for how many time?